# Microsoft Office 2016 Error "We're sorry something went wrong ... 0x8004FC12"

Tags: office365, software-activation, microsoft-office-2016

When starting up Microsoft Office 365 or Office 2016 for first time, I'm getting an error "We're sorry something went wrong and we can't do this for you right now. Please try again later (0x8004FC12)". Later apparently means never. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution search reveals lots of unhelpful websites with garbage answers. Here's the solution that worked for me. Enter the following in a Command prompt (DOS box) which has Administrator privleges. See [Office 365 Activation Fix](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_365hp-office_install/office-365-home-activation-error-were-sorry/fbb8c791-2e0c-4872-b742-8aec7e01ca23/) for more info. Can someone explain why these steps have become necessary?

```
  net localgroup Administrators localservice /add
  fsutil resource setautoreset true C:\
  netsh int ip reset resetlog.txt      (might be optional command)
```

Comment: Explanation can be found in the link of my own answer. Your answer can indeed be right as a second solution if mine fails, so no need to down vote this.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this happens when the `Microsoft Office Click-to-Run Service` become disabled. In my case I completely **disabled** it instead of setting it to **manual** start some time before the error occurred, and forgot that I did it. [THIS](http://www.technicalnotes.org/fix-something-went-wrong-errors-in-office-20132016365-in-windows-10/) page has some additional useful information and solutions for related errors.

**Solution-1**

Find the windows service application and run it. Then look for the *Click-to-Run* entry and make sure it is set to start. Then start it manually and try starting word (or excel etc) again.

Alternatively, if you're a command line junkie, you can accomplish the same  through the Admin CMD window or Power Shell:

```
sc config clicktorunsvc start=auto
sc start clicktorunsvc
```

For other error and more details, see the link I provided.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a very common problem with ClickToRun installations of Office, as there are a lot of customers complaining on the Microsoft Answers forums. Microsoft published an [article about this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/-Something-went-wrong-error-when-you-try-to-start-an-Office-app-4b4471dd-cf86-4a37-910d-35a01a6c7d17?rs=en-US&ui=en-US&ad=US) but it usually doesn't help. Also the "Microsoft Fix it" program usually doesn't help.

In my experience none of the suggested workarounds helped. If you have an old-style installation media (non ClickToRun), try with that. Otherwise, probably the only solution is to reinstall Windows to cleanup the mess that ClickToRun left in the Registry.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively clear out **everything** Microsoft Office 2013/365/2016  with a Microsoft tool

**Option 2 - Completely uninstall Office with the easy fix tool**

https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Uninstall-Office-2016-Office-2013-or-Office-365-from-a-PC-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB

Then install your desired version again.

Worked for me.